# TFS Eclipse plugin change default Check in Action to Associate

Tags: eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin

I have Eclipse Neon with TFS plugin

When I check pending change and I relate to work item

The problem is that the Check in Action by default is Resolve and not Associate

How do I change the default?

All I found online is about visual studio which didn't help me.

(Registry not worked HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio**11.0**\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior @ResolveAsDefaultCheckinAction = "False")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this could not be achieved in team explorer everywhere(TFS Eclipse plugin) for now.

As a workaround,  you could edit the Work Item Template definition for the types of work items you are using (Bug, Task, etc.). Then **remove the Check-In Action** from the Work Item Template (WIT). Once the WITs have been updated into your team project **this will be available for all users**.  Now when you add a related work item, the only option available is Associate. However, this solution has some pros and cons. Below is a few to consider:

> **Pros**
>
> - This change only has to be made the Team Project and nothing has to    be done on the clients.
> - If your team not resolve the work item, removing this option is not a    big deal.
>
> **Cons**
>
> - This would need to be applied to all current Team Projects and would
>        need to update the Process Template for future Team Projects.
> - This removes the Resolve option for users, so there is no way to    perform this action anymore.

More details about how to remove resolve option, please refer *DaveShaw*'s answer in  this question: [How to disable auto done status for task in checkin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263972/how-to-disable-auto-done-status-for-task-in-checkin)